# Authentication error while accessing Uber APIs

Tags: uber-api

I wanted to use Uber APIs so that i can book cabs on the behalf of user. I have provided all the details required in Uber developer dashboard.This is my request "`https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests`", and in body i'm sending three parameters(Authorization,Accept-Language and Content-Type) but while requesting it's showing this message:

> {   "message": "Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.",   "code":
>   "unauthorized" }

Comment: There is a lot that can go wrong between your intended request and what you are actually sending.  Including working or sample code with your tokens redacted would make it a lot easier to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting three *headers*, but how do you set them? Assuming you already obtained an `access_token` for your user, here's how you can make an authorized API call to [/v1.2/requests](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post):

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
     '{"product_id": "-", "start_latitude":"-", "start_longitude": "-", "end_latitude":"-", "end_longitude": "-", "seat_count": "-", "fare_id":"-"}' \
     https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests
```

Based on your question, I would also suggest to follow [this tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/curl) for more clarity. It guides you through the process of obtaining an `access_token` and making a ride request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply .In that tutorial to get access token,url was:"login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token".To get the access token in header i'm sending client_id,client_secret,grant_type as "authorization_code" ,redirect_uri as "http://localhost" and code as what i got from step1. I'm getting this message { "error": "unsupported_grant_type"}. I have tried every possible way but no progress.Thanks for reaching.